# xamarin forms app freezes while binding to nullable datetime

Tags: xaml, xamarin

While trying to show data over form in Xamarin Forms app, a property in the model which is nullable DateTime is freezing the app. I know this is the offending property because if I remove Xaml for this binding, everything works fine.

While stepping through the code, the **LoginTime** property from source (fetched from db) and the getter from ViewModel's User property are going into infinite loop. I can't possibly imagine why.

Model:

```
        public class User : PersistentEntity
    {
        private string _userId;
        public string UserId
        {
            get => _userId;
            set => SetProperty(ref _userId, value);
        }
    
        private string _userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get => _userName;
            set => SetProperty(ref _userName, value);
        }
    
        private string _email;
        public string Email
        {
            get => _email;
            set => SetProperty(ref _email, value);
        }
    
        private DateTime? _loginTime;
        public DateTime? LoginTime
        {
            get => _loginTime;
            set => SetProperty(ref _loginTime, value);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly SettingsSession _settingsSession;

        private User _user;
        public User User
        {
            get => _user;
            set => SetProperty(ref _user, value);
        }


        public SettingsViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, SettingsSession settingsSession)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Settings";

            _settingsSession = settingsSession;
        }

        private DelegateCommand _fetchUserCommand;
        public DelegateCommand FetchUserCommand =>
            _fetchUserCommand ?? (_fetchUserCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteFetchUserCommand, CanExecuteFetchUserCommand));

        async void ExecuteFetchUserCommand()
        {
           User = await _settingsSession.FetchUser();
        }

        bool CanExecuteFetchUserCommand()
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

View:

```
    <TableView Intent="Settings">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="User">

                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="2">
                        <Label Text="User Id"
                               WidthRequest="150" 
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Entry WidthRequest="250" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Placeholder="UserId" 
                               Text="{Binding User.UserId}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="2">
                        <Label Text="User Name"
                               WidthRequest="150" 
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Entry WidthRequest="250" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Placeholder="User Name" 
                               Text="{Binding User.UserName}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="2">
                        <Label Text="Login Time"
                               WidthRequest="150" 
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Entry WidthRequest="250" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               Placeholder="Login Time" 
                               Text="{Binding User.LoginTime, StringFormat='{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}'}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code you post looks well. I can't reproduce the issue that the getter from ViewModel's User property are going into infinite loop. Can you please share us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: BTW, DateTime is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. I have tried to create a minimal reproducible example but can't reproduce the error in the new solution. This is typical to the current solution I have which accesses a web service to login and I want to show the login time in the UI.

Comment: Are you setting a null value to LoginTime?

Comment: The login time comes from a web service to which the user logs in, the particulars of login will be saved to a local sqlite db. I just want to show the last login time to the user. But if the login is successful, the login time will have a value.

Comment: Can you please share me a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  The code you shared looks well and I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Hi @Jack, I have today tried again and surprisingly it didn't freeze. It actually worked. So, beats me why it wasted a whole day when I couldn't figure out what the issue was! Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can compare those two projects carefully and find out the difference.

Comment: This is the debug output: Binding: '17-11-2020 10:51:52' can not be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'.